# Where is a good place to get WinEdt help?

Tags: winedt

There used to be a Yahoo group for WinEdt users, but it (and Yahoo groups) seem to be defunct. Is there a good place for questions about WinEdt in particular?

Or is this the place?

EDIT: Apparently, I was misinformed.

Comment: There is a mailing list. See http://www.winedt.com/support.html about how to subscribe.

Comment: There is also the FAQs http://www.winedt.com/FAQs.html and user guide http://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.pdf and may still be some good info at **old user FAQs** http://www.winedt.org/old/Doc/FAQ/ but treat with caution and compare with current usage as its now 14 years old

Comment: The yahoo group is still accessible via https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/WinEdt/conversations/messages?

Comment: Huh.  I could have sworn that they had disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look to the [Homepage of Winedt](http://www.winedt.com/).  There you can find [the support via mailing list](http://www.winedt.com/support.html)!